# Custom Route Handler (for OPTIONS) if registered before config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() not working

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I am trying to fully implement a true RESTful Web API.  As part of this, I'm trying to expose OPTIONS through the Web API.  I'm using ASP.NET 5.2.0 (Web Api 2.2)

Here's the setup:
In my Application_Start, I register by Attribute Routing as the first line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)
```

The WebApiConfig is simple:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I then call a method that loops through all the routes that were registered and adds a new route per unique route template with an HttpMethodConstraint.

Here's what that class looks like

```
public class HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler
    : DelegatingHandler
{
    #region Class Variables
    /// <summary>
    /// The different supporting route actions for a specific route
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<ApiDescription> _routeInfo = new ApiDescription[0];
    #endregion

    #region Class Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the handler to return information based on the list of route information provided
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="routeInfo">A list of <see cref="ApiDescription"/> containing information about the different actions supported by a template</param>
    private HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> routeInfo)
    {
        _routeInfo = routeInfo;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Class Methods
    private static void AddOptionsRouteHandler(HttpRouteCollection routeTable, string routeTemplate, IEnumerable<ApiDescription> routeInfo)
    {
        //Define the handler for this particular route template and limit it to OPTIONS HTTP verb
        HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler handler = new HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler(routeInfo);
        HttpRouteValueDictionary constraints = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
        constraints.Add("httpMethod", new System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Options));

        //Create the route and add it to the route table
        IHttpRoute route = routeTable.CreateRoute(routeTemplate, null, constraints, null, handler);

        routeTable.Add(string.Format("OPTIONS-{0}", routeTemplate), route);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers this handler on all defined routes in configuraiton
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        HttpRouteCollection route_table = config.Routes;
        if (!route_table.Any())
            return;

        //Get the unique list of route templates
        IEnumerable<string> route_templates = route_table.Select<IHttpRoute, string>(route => route.RouteTemplate.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();

        //Using the API Explorer, find all the supporting information for these routes
        IApiExplorer explorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
        IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apis = explorer.ApiDescriptions;
        foreach (string route_template in route_templates)
        {
            IEnumerable<ApiDescription> route_info = apis.Where(api => string.Equals(api.Route.RouteTemplate, route_template, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            AddOptionsRouteHandler(route_table, route_template, route_info);
        }
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
            {
                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Everything is ok");
            });
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So the first 2 lines in Application_Start are:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler.Register);
```

Now when I try to check it out, expecting a 200 OK response with content of "Everything is OK", everything is not OK.  I'm getting the 405 METHOD NOT ACCEPTED response.

I switched the 2 lines in Application_Start so that HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler.Register is called first.  Also added a quick hack to register a route template of "" and then exit out because HTTPOptionsVerbMessageHandler.Register requires there to be routes, which of course there aren't any since WebApiConfig.Register hasn't been called yet.

In this case, OPTIONS "" as well as my Attribute Based route of GET "" both work as expected.

So what am I doing wrong in the creation of my route where it's not being detected?  Do I need to add or create routes differently?  It's not the web.config because when I switch the order, it works correctly.  It has something to do with how I'm registering these custom routes, but can't figure out what.